# Error in regular expression for e-mail addresses

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression to validate an e-mail address. It looks like

```
^[a-z0-9]+([-+._][a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9]+([-.][a-z0-9]{2,})*\.[a-z0-9]+([-.][a-z0-9]{2,})*$
```

In most cases it works properly but when I type the e-mail like "qwerty_@mail.com" this regular expression does not match, although it is a correct e-mail address. Addresses like `qwerty_1@mail.com` do match.
How can I fix this expression to avoid this error?

Comment: In most cases ? http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Answer (score 1):

This part (at the beginning):

```
[a-z0-9]+([-+._][a-z0-9]+)*
```

Is causing the problem. It's saying you want 1 or more letters or number, followed by 0 or more iterations of a combination of a symbol and 1 or more letters. You probably wanna say "a letter or number at the start and then any of the following characters 0 or more times" like so:

```
[a-z0-9][a-z0-9+._-]*
```

The part after the `@` is allowing dashes for dots, are you sure this is what you want? In the interest of doing more than just giving you the code that "works", take a look at [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/NcPF80sPlad51ViF) to see how your current regex works so you can improve it :) Gives this nice visual view:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Escape the dash in the character class or move it at the beginig or at the end.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex to validating the emails

```
^[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z1-9][\.\-\_]?[A-Za-z1-9]?)+@[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]{3,}$
```

Comment: Why use it? some explanation might be helpful.

Comment: This allows `---@---.xx`.

Comment: Doesn't allow tld like 'museum'

Comment: @sp00m this is not invalid for the new regex

Comment: @l'L'l you can check it again

Comment: Now it doesn't match countries tdl (us, fr, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a good reason don't use self rolled regex to validate email addresses. They are a complex beast and [someone else has already done the work for you](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Valid)!

Here's how to use the module

```
# Gives us say and always a good idea
use Modern::Perl;

use Email::Valid;

my @addrs = qw/ qwerty_@mail.com
                qwerty_1@mail.com
                qwerty\@mail.com  /;
foreach (@addrs) {
    print "$_ is ";
    print 'in' unless Email::Valid->address($_);
    say   'valid'
}
```

Which outputs

```
qwerty_@mail.com is valid
qwerty_1@mail.com is valid
qwerty\@mail.com is invalid
```

I actually discovered this module in answering this question and it's better than the one I was using before. So thanks very much for asking :)